# USB-Serial adapter : Serial device receives no power when running msdn example

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to read data from a serial device. It has an LED that turns on when I connect it to an actual serial port (on an old XP machine).
On my target machine however, I need to use a USB-serial adapter, and the LED does not turn on when connecting it.
It does turn on when I open the serial port with Putty or Hyperterminal though.

Now I have been trying to read it in my .Net project, and in order to do that, i run the example code from the MSDN documentation here :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

when I do, nothing gets read from the port, and the LED does not even turn on. I would expect it to turn on whenever I hit the

_serialPort.Open();

but it does not.

Is there a specific step, or configuration, or workaound, to ensure the serial port receives power when using USB adapters?

My serial device is a GlobalCaché GC-IRE.
The USB adapters I have been testing: 3 different ones, two no-names and one TrendNet TU-S9.

Comment: Standard mistake is to ignore the need to set the Handshake property.  Next thing to try is to set the DtrEnable and RtsEnable properties to *true*.  Those signals tell the device that you are powered up and ready to receive data.  Usually good enough to let it turn on an LED and start thinking about actually sending data.

Comment: The device's user manual says to set Flow Control to None, so I set handshake to Handshake.None. Setting DtrEnable to False and RtsEnable does make the LED work as I would expect. I still can not read anything from the port though.

Comment: Hmya, you've got two choices and I did not recommend using False.

Comment: Indeed I had switched one of them back to false in an effort to trouble shoot. My Readline now works provided I set my NewLine property to "\r" instead of the default "\n". So, setting DtrEnable and RtsEnable to true is the answer to my question, thanks. Please put it as an answer below and I will accept it as answer.